# How to prevent "woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart" this from redirecting to cart page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating custom shortcode for product display in home page in which i am displaying image with title, quantity and Add to cart button for that i am using below code:

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',     'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
   function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
$html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
$html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
$html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
$html .= '</form>';
}
return $html;
```

}

Somehow this code is redirecting so i thought why not use Hook so i tried this:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
    function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ){
      do_action('woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart');
    }
```

But both are not working it redirects to cart page.
When clicking on add to cart button items should be added to the cart and page should be as it is should not redirect or refresh.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you disable the "Cart Redirection" inside the WooCommerce settings?

WooCommerce > Settings > Products Tab

[image]

Step #2

Well, in case it didn't help, try to use `wp_get_referer`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'wp_get_referer' );
```

In case you want a custom redirection, you can find the filter below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_redirect_function' );
    function custom_redirect_function() {
    return get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
}
```

Comment: Hey Mora this is not working i have already tried this.

Comment: Hey @tejal, please, check the update

Comment: Unfortunately both are not working.

Comment: Do I get it right that you paste the code into the functions.php file?

Comment: Yes i copy pasted the exact code in function.php

Comment: Could you, please, disable all plugins? Some plugins like Min/Max Quantity add their own custom redirection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239807/discussion-between-tejal-and-mora-fe).